# Null pointer expection with firebaseauthentification

Tags: flutter, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

I created a Firebase authentification with a tutorial and did excactly what the person did. It throwed a Null pointer expection. It is a firebaseauthentification with username and password.
I created a user in firebase and enabled this type of authentification.
I am quite sure that I have added all the important stuff to the gradles. 
It still threw the expection, so i  have watched another tutorial, the same thing happend. The terminal shows

```
 E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(14073): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference
```

I have no sync gradles button in my AndroidStudio and my gradles show this error

Cannot resolve symbol "Properties" and Cannot resolve Symbol "GradleException"

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

Could some of these things be the issue?

Comment: Did you download google json file and placed it in your project?

Comment: yes, I did what google said in the short tutorial

Comment: Can you link to tutorial? I will try it out.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMrBwLw1DIU

this is the first I tried, but it is longer: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_Lyx8KJWpg

Comment: tried it again, with a new project. Another error, which appeard in the first project too. `'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 224 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true.`   This error appears only when nothing is in the textfield. When I insert something, the application does nothing. It shows just the same screen without an error.

Comment: Got a minimal example to work and wrote about it on my blog https://www.thetechremix.com/2019/09/my-experience-authentication-with.html. Let me know if that helps.